# BlockChain : Issue setting up dev environment for hyperledger fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I am a beginner in the blockchain technology and wanted to get some hands on by setting up a dev environment for hyperledger fabric.

I tried to setup the dev environment and was following the official documentation at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

In the step when I call the script network_setup.sh to bring the network up, It fails at the last step with an error as -

> ...
>   ...
>   Trying to pull repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-testenv ..
>   Pulling repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-testenv
>   ERROR: Error: image hyperledger/fabric-testenv not found

The image itself is not available in the repository and hence the script fails.

Can someone guide me on how to overcome this and where can I find good references for setting up a fabric dev environment.

Comment: It looks like that [that image doesn't exist on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/hyperledger/) (as the error suggests). Given the test name, I wonder if it was left in the script by accident...

Comment: I agree with @JeremyBanks, you don't need the fabric-testenv to get started. You should try to remove the reference to this image and see where it goes

Comment: Thanks Erik / Jeremy... Will try commenting the cli section and see if I am able to bring the network up... In case you have come across anywhere ( url ) where they provide the steps for setting up the fabric environment it would greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something blew up, so the URL had to be changed. The instructions have been updated, and the curl command points to a new URL now. Try it again, should work now. change logged here https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/8591/