# Yet Another "ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest not found" error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Part of the answer (!) to this question is that I must know (in advance) that this is a problem, identify the images that I must pull (here's [Orderer](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-orderer/tags/)) and then retag them all with "latest". This seems *sub-optimal*. I know this problem because I've experienced it before, but... I'm being a noob and following along here:

Excited Noob wanting to [write first app](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html)

Dutifully follows along with [Prereqs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html)

Then

```
/startFabric.sh

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Removing network net_basic
WARNING: Network net_basic not found.

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Pulling orderer.example.com (hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest)...
ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest not found
```

Noob departs frustrated?

Please revise the tutorial page to reference this additional pre-req

Or parameterize scripts to take `DOCKER_TAG={{VALUE}}`

Or am I missing something?

These instructions could be:

Identify the latest version for your architecture using "fabric-orderer" as a template:
https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-orderer/tags/

In my case the latest tag is `x86_64-1.0.3` and I'm using bash, so:

```
TAG={{THE CORRECT VALUE}} // In my case x86_64-1.0.3
for IMAGE in orderer couchdb peer ca tools
do
  docker pull hyperledger/fabric-${IMAGE}:${TAG} && \
  docker tag \
    hyperledger/fabric-${IMAGE}:${TAG} \
    hyperledger/fabric-${IMAGE}:latest
done
```

References:

- [ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830372/error-manifest-for-hyperledger-fabric-ordererlatest-not-found)
- [hyperledger fabric tutoral - write first application error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366905/hyperledger-fabric-tutoral-write-first-application-error)
- [Error building images: Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644889/error-building-images-tag-latest-not-found-in-repository-docker-io-hyperledger)
- [BlockChain : Issue setting up dev environment for hyperledger fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786147/blockchain-issue-setting-up-dev-environment-for-hyperledger-fabric)

Answer (score 1):

What you missing is the step where you have to download binaries, see ["Download Platform-specific Binaries"](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html#binaries).

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.3.sh | bash
```

PS. you can find more explanation on one of your references, e.g.:

- ["hyperledger fabric tutoral - write first application error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366905/hyperledger-fabric-tutoral-write-first-application-error)

Comment: Thanks. I'm proposing that someone update the pre-req's document to include these instructions since so many of us seem to get hit by this known issue. I think, rather than try to fudge the "latest" tag for different architectures, the scripts should expect an environment variable LATEST_TAG or similar.